# Excel - Auto populate a date column based on ID, start date and sequence (reference)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my workbook, I have 4 columns. Column A is ID, column B is Effective date (start date), column C is sequence (which is reference number for duplicated data from column A and B) and finally column D, End date. I want to match Column A, B and C and see whether it is the last record of the same day by the same employee (determine by the ID).

For example (sample result i want):

```
 A        B        C        D
1001  12/03/2018   1    12/03/2018
1001  12/03/2018   2    12/03/2018
1001  12/03/2018   3    12/03/2018
1001  12/03/2018   4    31/12/2018
1001  13/03/2018   1    13/03/2018
1001  13/03/2018   2    31/12/2018
1001  14/03/2018   1    31/12/2018
1002  12/03/2018   1    12/03/2018
1002  12/03/2018   2    31/12/2018
1002  13/03/2018   1    31/12/2018
```

As you can see, employee ID 1001 have 4 records in 12/03/2018, so column A and B will duplicate for 4 times, so i add in a column C to determine which record is enter into the sheet first. Then the End Date (column D) for the first 3 record will have the same date as Column B but the last record (sequence number 4) it will have an end date 31/12/2018. I need column D to be auto populate by comparing Column A,B and C.

Previously, I found a IF function like this

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,$A2)=$C2,DATEVALUE("31/12/2018"),$B2)
```

It works if the ID 1001 stopped at sequence 4 but it won't work if a new date inserted for ID 1001 (example, 1001 with the date 13/03/2018).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IF(SUM(IF(A:A&B:B=$A2&$B2,1))=$C2,DATEVALUE("31/12/2018"),$B2)`

This is an array formula, validated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar.

`SUM(IF(A:A&B:B=$A2&$B2,1))` is being used as an equivalent to `COUNTIFS()` as I needed to append the date value to your ID to produce a unique value per day and `COUNTIFS()` only operates on a range rather than an array.

`A1&B1` is a lazy way of achieving `CONCATENATE(A1,B1)` to tie string values together, we do this for both sides of our `IF()` logical so that we can assess the array:

```
{"100143171";"100143171";"100143171";"100143171";"100143172";"100143172";"100143173";"100243171";"100243171";"100243172"}
```

instead of using just A:A:

```
{1001;1001;1001;1001;1001;1001;1001;1002;1002;1002}
```

The reason we need this to be an array formula is so that `SUM()` assesses all of the returned values from `IF()` individually. The best way to understand what a formula does in pieces is to use F9 when highlighting the section. You will need to narrow the results from being whole columns though as it will need to fit in the formula bar.

Comment: Fantastic. It seems like the solution I need!. Thanks.

Comment: If you can briefly explain this part of the formula SUM(IF(A:A&B:B=$A2&$B2,1) I will be even more thankful. I'm still very newbie in Excel.

Comment: Sure, I'll do an edit on the post and nudge you when it's done

Comment: Thank you very much. Very appreciate your help.

Comment: @Rexksvii Updated... If you're still unclear feel free to give me a nudge and I'll try to provide more clarity

Comment: I guess I understand what you trying to say. Just one more question, the 1 inside the nested IF statement, is it means that it will return 1 if A:A&B:B = A2&B2? Then the SUM function will sum up all the value 1 returned by the IF function, am I correct?

Comment: This is correct, it basically builds another array of `{1,1,1,1,FALSE,FALSE` etc that is summed

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. It works perfectly in my actual data sheet!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an array formula you can always use `=COUNTIFS()`

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)=C2,DATEVALUE("31/12/2018"),B2)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Your solution worked as well. Good to know some alternative way to achieved the same result! Btw, your way seems like consume lesser processing resources than array formula. I think it would be a better options if the data load is huge.

Comment: Yes, an Excel built-in function should be faster than an array formula.  You should also limit your range to the number of data points you are analyzing or a range that would always include the max number of records instead of using A:A . Or use a dynamic named range that would expand to include all records.